# *LONG* Execution Time - Mutual Interests

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I'm running into a problem that I suspect is down to my inability to craft an efficient CYPHER query, and general lack of neo4j experience.

**Background:**

I have a relatively large dataset that seems to be choking when finding mutual 'likes' between a user and their 2nd degree friends.

**Current stats:**

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ dbinfo -g "Primitive count"
{
  "NumberOfNodeIdsInUse": 9343080,
  "NumberOfPropertyIdsInUse": 25416540,
  "NumberOfRelationshipIdsInUse": 47270718,
  "NumberOfRelationshipTypeIdsInUse": 8
}

------

Numbers:
Users: ~ 2 million
Likes: ~ 7 million
Users Likes: ~ 22 million
```

**Indexes:**

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ schema
Indexes
  ON :Employer(origin_id)       ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)
  ON :Group(origin_id)          ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)
  ON :Like(category)            ONLINE
  ON :Like(origin_id)           ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)
  ON :Location(country_code)    ONLINE
  ON :Location(country)         ONLINE
  ON :Location(origin_id)       ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)
  ON :School(origin_id)         ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)
  ON :User(registered)          ONLINE
  ON :User(relationship_status) ONLINE
  ON :User(interested_in)       ONLINE
  ON :User(gender)              ONLINE
  ON :User(age)                 ONLINE
  ON :User(origin_id)           ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)
  ON :User(uid)                 ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)

Constraints
  ON (user:User) ASSERT user.uid IS UNIQUE
  ON (school:School) ASSERT school.origin_id IS UNIQUE
  ON (user:User) ASSERT user.origin_id IS UNIQUE
  ON (group:Group) ASSERT group.origin_id IS UNIQUE
  ON (employer:Employer) ASSERT employer.origin_id IS UNIQUE
  ON (like:Like) ASSERT like.origin_id IS UNIQUE
  ON (location:Location) ASSERT location.origin_id IS UNIQUE
```

**Slow Queries:**
http://pastebin.com/MPZ3aXCs

**Issue:**

The first query executes in about 12 seconds for this user, returning 909 rows. Still very slow.

The second query executes in about 70 seconds for this user. The immediate issue for me is that trying to search through the mutual interests of a matched friend of friend (line 33) causes a dramatic increase in time. I also notice that adding this match seems to create a second EAGER 'branch' in the profile. During this time CPU is absolutely pinned.

If I take a step back and simply match the mutual interests between two users the query is executed in < 50ms.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ PROFILE MATCH (u:User {origin_id:2043})-[:LIKES]->(l:Like)<-[:LIKES]-(u2:User {origin_id:1212817}) return l;
3 rows

ColumnFilter
  |
  +Filter
    |
    +TraversalMatcher

+------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|         Operator | Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |                                Other |
+------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|     ColumnFilter |    3 |      0 |             |                       keep columns l |
|           Filter |    3 |      0 |             |      NOT(  UNNAMED31 ==   UNNAMED50) |
| TraversalMatcher |    3 |   1114 |             | u2,   UNNAMED50, u2,   UNNAMED31, u2 |
+------------------+------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 1114
```

We are currently looking to extend this query out to match the users 3rd degree friends which right now is seemingly impossible.

I should also note that I'm running this on a standalone AWS c3.xlarge (4 vCPU / 8GB RAM) which does nothing else except host neo4j. The server configs are more or less standard default. Happy to provide them if necessary.

**Ideally,** I'd want to have this information returned in a single query due to the way its processed afterwards.

Any help optimizing these queries would be greatly appreciated. If I've missed any key pieces of information here, please let me know.

**Edit:** Using Neo4J 2.1.6

**Edit 2:**

I've made some changes to the query which seem to reduce the number of dbhits almost in half. The time taken for the query has now reduced down to ~ 16 seconds.

The new query with profile is available here: http://pastebin.com/UyFi89H7

Are there more optimisations I can make, aside from using extra criteria to filter down the friends of friends?

Comment: Your linked second query looks like a very different query from the first.

Comment: Michael I've changed it to be slightly more efficient. It still seems to pull back the same data.

Answer (score 1):

First kudos for a nice detailed question.

Secondly, By looking at the beginning of your Cypher queries, the suggestion I can give you is to start with a small start point, for e.g. start by first matching your user, then pass it to the next step with WITH. Then retrieve his location, pass the user and the location with WITH.

As you can see in the profile of your first query, he will start with a Traversal Matcher and not benefit from label and property indexes.

First optimization to put you on the road :

```
PROFILE
MATCH (user:User {origin_id:138})
WITH user
MATCH (user)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(userLoc:Location), (user)-[fr:FRIENDS_WITH*2]->(fof:User)
WHERE
    user.origin_id <> fof.origin_id
    AND NOT (user)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]->(fof)
```

With the above query, he will use the indexes to retrieve your user and not the traversal matcher.

Comment: Thanks Christophe. I've taken that on board and am trying to apply the same logic for the rest of the query - with varying results. Any more advice and guidance would be hugely appreciated.

The biggest challenge seems to be passing the matched nodes down the query. Moving the likes search up the query yields positive results until I follow on with a FOF query.

Comment: would you be able to provide some test data ?

Comment: also in your query, the fof location node you look for should be the same node than your userLoc node ?

Comment: I wish it were but locations in my case are at quite a micro level.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try:

```
MATCH (u:User {origin_id:2043}),(u2:User {origin_id:1212817})
MATCH path = allShortestPaths((u1)-[:LIKES*..2]-(u2)) 
RETURN nodes(path)[1] as like
```

Try to reduce the cardinality as early as possible to the minimum possible,
instead of matching for every fof several times, try to aggregate to one instance of fof first and match then

```
PROFILE
MATCH (user:User {origin_id:138})-[:LIVES_IN]->(userLoc:Location)-[:IN_COUNTRY]->(country)
MATCH (user)-[fr:FRIENDS_WITH]->(friend:User)-[fofr:FRIENDS_WITH]->(fof:User)
WHERE (fof.dob_age <= 35 AND fof.dob_age >= 20)
WITH user, count(distinct friend) as mutual_friend_count, collect(distinct friend) as mutual_friends, fof,
     (ABS(user.dob_age - fof.dob_age)) as age_diff, userLoc, country

WHERE (fof)-[:LIVES_IN]->(fofLoc:Location)-[:IN_COUNTRY]->(country)

RETURN
    fof.origin_id as fof_origin_id,
    fof.first_name as fof_first_name,
    fof.last_name as fof_last_name,
    fof.dob_age as fof_age,
    user.dob_age as user_age,
    userLoc.latitude as user_loc_latitude,
    userLoc.longitude as user_loc_longitude,
    fofLoc.name as fof_loc_name,
    fofLoc.latitude as fof_loc_latitude,
    fofLoc.longitude as fof_loc_longitude,
    age_diff as age_diff,
    mutual_friend_count, mutual_friends
```